# Web Scraping com selenium WebDriver e python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, ipython-notebook

Este programa tem o intuito de baixar arquivos excel para otimizar o tempo. Mas existe os filtros para serem preenchidos antes de baixar o arquivo, nesses filtros tem a data de inicio e data fim, deve ser a mesma data pois o tempo não pode passar de 24 horas, então estou tendo que alterar manualmente as duas datas no código antes de baixar cada arquivo e isso está se tornando repetitivo.

Aqui está a parte onde altero as datas:

```
#selecionar data
start_date = (By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_txtDataIni")
element_start_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(start_date))
element_start_date.clear()
element_start_date.send_keys('31/01/2021')

end_date = (By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_txtDataFim")
element_end_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(end_date))
element_end_date.clear()
element_end_date.send_keys('31/01/2021')
```

Aqui está o código na integra:

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')


## Endereço do site da coleta
url = "https://gool.cittati.com.br/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f"

driver.get(url)
#time.sleep(5)

## Logar 
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='listaIcones']//ul//li//input[@id='ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano']")
login.click()

txt_username_locator = (By.ID, "ucLogarUsuario_txtLogin")       # colocando usuario
element_username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(txt_username_locator)) 
element_username.send_keys("###")

txt_passwoard_locator = (By.ID, "ucLogarUsuario_txtSenha")      # colocando senha
element_password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(txt_passwoard_locator))
element_password.send_keys("###")
element_password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

## Acessar o monitoramento:

monitoring = (By.NAME, "item_menu_1")
element_monitoring =  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(monitoring))
element_monitoring.click()

## Acessar os relatorios e historico de eventos:

reports = (By.ID, "item_menu_2") 
element_reports = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(reports))
element_reports.click()

event_history = (By.ID, "50204")
element_event_history = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(event_history))
element_event_history.click()

## pesquisar eventos. 

#selecionar data
start_date = (By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_txtDataIni")
element_start_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(start_date))
element_start_date.clear()
element_start_date.send_keys('31/01/2021')

end_date = (By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_txtDataFim")
element_end_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(end_date))
element_end_date.clear()
element_end_date.send_keys('31/01/2021')

#selecionar tipo de eventos
select_event = (By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_ddlEvento")
element_select_event = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(select_event))
element_select_event.send_keys('Cumprimento de Viagem')

#selecionar todas as linhas
select_line = (By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_chkSelevionarTodosLinhas")
element_select_line = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(select_line))
element_select_line.click()

#baixar arquivo excel contendo os dados
document_excel = (By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_btnExportarExcel")
element_document_excel = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(document_excel))
element_document_excel.click()

#driver.quit()
```

Tentei fazer um contador e ir alterando as datas, mas não obtive exito. Alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar uma solução para automatizar este processo para que não seja necessário fechar o programa alterar a data manualmente e rodar novamente.

Comment: Samuel, não entendi qual a sua duvida, por favor seja mais especifico, o que você deseja fazer e o que não esta dando certo?

Comment: Eu quero baixar arquivos referente a cada dia, mas não quero ter que trocar a data e executar o projeto toda a vez, gostaria de baixar todos arquivos de um mês ou até de um ano executando o projeto apenas uma vez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

***Você chegou inserir a parte para fazer o download dentro do loop?***

Olá, não tenho pontuação para comentar, então tenho que colocar como resposta.

Se entendi corretamente, você quer desenvolver uma forma de montar as datas.

Pensei em um loop for:

```
dias = list(range(1, 32))
meses = list(range(1, 13))
anos = list(range(2020, 2022))

for ano em anos:
    for mes in meses:
        for dia in dias:
            if mes == 2 and dia >= 28:
                break
            elif mes in [4, 6, 9, 11] and dia > 30:
                break
            data = f'{str(dia)}/{str(mes)}/{str(ano)}'
            start_date = (By.ID, 
            "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_txtDataIni")
            element_start_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 
            20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(start_date))
            element_start_date.clear()
            element_start_date.send_keys(data)
            element_end_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 
            20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(end_date))
            element_end_date.clear()
            element_end_date.send_keys(data)
            #selecionar tipo de eventos
            select_event = (By.ID, 
            "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_ddlEvento")
            element_select_event = WebDriverWait(driver, 
            20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(select_event))
            element_select_event.send_keys('Cumprimento de Viagem')

            #selecionar todas as linhas
            select_line = (By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_chkSelevionarTodosLinhas")
            element_select_line = WebDriverWait(driver, 
            20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(select_line))
            element_select_line.click()

            #baixar arquivo excel contendo os dados
            document_excel = (By.ID, 
            "ContentPlaceHolder1_contentFiltroPesquisa_btnExportarExcel")
            element_document_excel = WebDriverWait(driver, 
            20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(document_excel))
            element_document_excel.click()
```

---

No range do loop você poderia inserir as datas que precisa, colocar step ou fazer uma lista com os dias que deseja.

Ao final se não consegue realizar novamente a pesquisa, você pode inserir um driver.refresh() para atualizar a página e poder refazer a operação.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Fiz o loop porém o loop não para para baixar o arquivo ele vai indo até a ultima data do loop e baixa apenas o arquivo da ultima data.

Comment: Eu gostaria que primeiro baixasse do dia 01, após isso voltasse no loop.

Comment: Sim, coloquei a parte do download dentro do loop, mas só faz o download quando percorre todo o loop e chega em 31 que seria a ultima data. Ai fiz uma lista como você havia dito, e coloquei um sleep no loop e deu certo. muito obrigado pela ajuda!